# JSON_OBJECT functionality in Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

Conditionally building JSON OBJECT in Mysql 5.7

Following query producing Null as an object

select JSON_OBJECT('abc','12345','id', CASE WHEN null is null THEN NULL ELSE JSON_OBJECT('a',1) END);

But expected result is {"abc": 12345, "id": null}

Comment: working fine in version '8.0.15'

Comment: it will work fine in mysql higher versions.

Answer (score 1):

After some time, found the solution: (from Mysql official documentation).

By using CAST('null' as JSON)

select JSON_OBJECT('abc','12345','id', CASE WHEN (null is null) THEN CAST('null' AS JSON) ELSE (JSON_OBJECT('a',1)) END);